# What are these operators for "/^ $/" and how does it work in this case?

Tags: javascript, operators, ternary-operator

recently I was doing challenges on codewars in JS and when you submit your code they show you how other people have done the challenge and this was one of the solutions. As I was looking through it I noticed these markers and I wanted to understand them and learn how to use them. There seems to be a "?" in the middle as well which leads to believe it has something to do with the ternary operator.

```
let data = [":~)", ";->", ";~(", ":~D", ";o>", ":)", ";oD"];

function countSmileys(data) {
    return data.filter(x => /^[:;][-~]?[)D]$/.test(x)).length;   
}
```

I might have a few vague ideas of what it might do, because I know what the output should be.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: nothing to do with ternary operators, that's a regular expression, what that function is trying to do is to filter the elements on the array

Comment: Those aren't operators in this context, they're part of a regex expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with ternary operators, that's a regular expression, what that function is trying to do is to filter the elements on the array.

```
function countSmileys(data) {
    //filter out the elements that don't match the regular expression you want to test
    return data.filter(x => /^[:;][-~]?[)D]$/.test(x)).length;   
}
```

you can read more about regular expression [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

and the `test` function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Answer (score 0):

what they are using are [regular expresions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)